# Why does `getAllPermissions()` with where condition isn't working in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working in larael9 with spatie package to manage roles and permissions.
I want to fetch user permissions with `where` condtion.

my `permissions` table is as following

```
id | name                           | guard_name    | created_at          | updated_at
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14 | admin_side_barmenu_dashboard   | web           | 2022-09-29 13:52:00 | 2022-09-29 13:52:00
    
15 | admin_side_barmenu_users       | web           | 2022-09-29 13:52:00 | 2022-09-29 13:52:00
    
16 | admin_side_barmenu_settings    | web           | 2022-09-29 13:52:00 | 2022-09-29 13:52:00
    
17 | admin_side_barmenu_roles       | web           | 2022-09-29 13:52:00 | 2022-09-29 13:52:00
    
18 | admin_side_barmenu_permission  | web           | 2022-09-29 13:52:00 | 2022-09-29 13:52:00
```

what i am trying to achieve is, get permissions were name start with `'admin_side_barmenu'` for auth user
I am able to get all the permissions but not able to get where it start with `'admin_side_barmenu'`.

I have tried the following way.

```
auth()->user()->getAllPermissions()->where('name', 'like', '%admin_side_barmenu%')->toArray();
```

Following is working for me if it fetchs with full name

```
auth()->user()->getAllPermissions()->where('name', 'like', 'admin_side_barmenu_dashboard')->toArray();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use `%` symbol at the end of your `where` clause value (eg: `admin_side_barmenu%`) so that the `DB` knows you only want the rows starting with `admin_side_barmenu` and can have 0 or more characters from the right.

### UPDATE

After checking the package, it seems `getAllPermissions` return a collection and doesn't make a *direct* DB call, So we need to filter the return collection from that method.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

auth()->user()
  ->getAllPermissions()
  ->filter(fn($p) => Str::startsWith($p, 'admin_side_barmenu')) // only return permissions starting with "admin_side_barmenu"
  ->toArray();
```

Based on the data sample found in your question, the above query should return **all the rows** from the table because they **all start with** `admin_side_barmenu` substring.

> Learn more about [`Pattern Matching`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html) on `MySQL` docs.

Comment: I have already tried this. This isn't working too.

Comment: So, what do you get as a result then ? Do you see any errors or something ?

Comment: I am getting empty array `Array()`.

Comment: @RamChander I have updated my answer, please check it out.

Comment: That's not working too :(

Comment: `str::startsWith` require 2 params

Comment: I have fixed this. please check my new answer. (i can't edit in ur question as it says suggested edit is full)

Comment: @RamChander indeed, `startsWith` requires 2 parameters that was a typo (I edited my answer). Glad I managed to help you. If you feel my answer was helpful, kindly set it as the accepted answer.

Comment: replace with `$p` with `$p->name`

Comment: @RamChander yes, but that depends on your data which i don't know what it contains. Anyway, glad you managed to overcome your issue.

Answer (score 0):

[**@ths**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6388552/ths)

Thank you so much for your time.

I have made some changes in your answer. and its working for me. Thanks for the help

```
auth()->user()
    ->getAllPermissions()
    ->filter(fn($p) => Str::startsWith($p->name, 'admin_side_barmenu',))
    ->toArray());
```